# Sending emails from outlook using python

Tags: python, outlook-restapi

I am trying to send meeting invites from outlook using python. I also want to reflect that in the outlook calendar of the receiver. I am using the following code

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
def sendRecurringMeeting():    
  appt = outlook.CreateItem(1) # AppointmentItem
  appt.Start = "2018-11-14 15:30" # yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm
  appt.Subject = "Important"
  appt.Duration = 60 # In minutes (60 Minutes)
  appt.Location = "Floor 5"
  appt.MeetingStatus = 1 # 1 - olMeeting; Changing the appointment to meeting. Only after changing the meeting status recipients can be added
  appt.Recipients.Add("mabc@abc.com") # Don't end ; as delimiter
  appt.Recipients.Add("xyz@xyz.com")
  appt.ReminderSet = True
  appt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
  # Set Pattern, to recur every day, for the next 5 days
  pattern = appt.GetRecurrencePattern()
  pattern.RecurrenceType = 0
  pattern.Occurrences = "1"
  appt.Save()
  appt.Send()
sendRecurringMeeting()
```

Here I am trying to send meeting invites from outlook with Python. Generally when we send a meeting invite, It starts showing in their calendar that you have a meeting today at the mentioned time. By using the above code, I am able to send a meeting invite but it is not showing in their calendar i.e it is not giving reminders.

Comment: For everyone who's not familiar with exactly this issue, it will be very hard to help you out. Please try to give more context and (although it might be hard in this particular situation) a better working example. Cf. [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In particular, show your imports statements so we can see exactly what packages you're using.  Where does `outlook` come from?

Comment: added outlook-restapi tag